# Automatic Numbering not incrementing

Tags: css, css-grid, css-counter

I want to recreate this picture using CSS, And I'm required to write the text using only CSS. I'm not allowed to edit the HTML code
[image: the required output]

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style:none;
    
}
.grid {
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
    
   

  }
  .grid div{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
  
    
  }
  .grid div::before{
    counter-reset: Element 0;
    counter-increment: Element 1;
    content: "Element " counter(Element);
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

It keeps showing only "Element 1"
I used simple CSS code by resetting the counter and then making an increment of 1. And showing the output in `content:counter(Element)`
[image: this is my output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `counter-reset` to parent `.grid`, also no need to set `0`

Note you can improve your `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto`, to `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto)`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

.grid {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  counter-reset: Element;
}

.grid div {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.grid div::before {
  counter-increment: Element;
  content: "Element " counter(Element);
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the reset and increment all on the pseudo (`::before`) element. This is incorrect and doesn't provide scope.

`counter-reset` needs to be on the parent, `counter-increment` on the element, and `counter` on the pseudo.

```
  .grid {
    counter-reset: Element;
  }

  .grid div {
    counter-increment: Element;
  }

  .grid div::before{
    content: "Element " counter(Element);
  }
```

See below

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style:none;
    
}
.grid {
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
    counter-reset: Element;

  }
  .grid div{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-increment: Element;
    
  }
  .grid div::before{
    content: "Element " counter(Element);
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
   <div class="grid">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You can increment in the pseudo element

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your `counter-reset` from the `.grid div::before` block.
Place it in the `.gid div` block instead. also by default it increments in 1 so its not necessary to display the `1` in `counter-increment`
Here are the docs that explain: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp

```
.grid div{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: Element;    
  }
  .grid div::before{
    counter-increment: Element;
    content: "Element " counter(Element);
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```